# some help with an excerpt from my reading material

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, sentence, meaning

I am reading a book for my church group, and in the book Jesus is saying to St. Faustina the following:

*"During this hour, I will refuse nothing to the soul that makes a request of me in virtue of my passion."*

When this sentence is taken literally, is it equivalent to:

*"During this hour, I will grant everything to the soul that makes a request of me in virtue of my passion"?*

PS: I am not asking for any theological interpretation, I am just asking for the *literal* interpretation. Simple "yes" or "no" would be sufficient for an answer.

Thank you,

Comment: That's roughly the way I'd read it.  It's a bit ambiguous as to what "in virtue of my passion implies" -- one could read it as applying to the request or to the granting.

Comment: I would use the Christianity or Catholic SE meta to have this question answered. You may find this in the top left corner of this page under the drop down arrow. Scroll down under 'More Stack Exchange Communities' until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: This is a duplicate of two earlier questions: [Meaning of “I will refuse nothing to the soul that makes a request of me”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245785/meaning-of-i-will-refuse-nothing-to-the-soul-that-makes-a-request-of-me) and [“I will refuse nothing to a soul that makes a request of me in virtue of my passion” - meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238897/i-will-refuse-nothing-to-a-soul-that-makes-a-request-of-me-in-virtue-of-my-pass)—both by the same poster (not user2792124), one month apart, by the way, and both still live on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - although I'd go with 'anything' rather than 'everything'.

Comment: As @andyb noted, there is a difference between granting whatever is asked for (but only that), versus granting everything when (only) something is asked.